# What is the point of Python egg files?

Tags: python, django, egg

When I run `python setup.py install` django, it generates an egg file.

What is the usefulness of Python egg files?

Answer (score 7):

The "egg" is Python's binary distribution format. It's basically a zipped file with some extra metadata that you can give another Python user. He can "install" and use them. For details on what they are, please refer to http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs.
Since it's a "native" format, Python can employ custom importers and the like.

For details on how to use them, check [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-cppeak3.html) out.

I've been out of touch with the packaging world for a while now. There was some talk of discontinuing support for binary distribution formats. The relevant documents that I know of are at http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/tip/docs/design/wiki.rst

Answer (score 1):

the egg file is an archive which holds a module (django in your case) and gives you the ability to `import something_from_egg`. Read more [here](http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/)