# What's the purpose of package.egg-info folder?

Tags: python

I'm developing a python package `foo`. My project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar.py
│   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── README.md
│   └── setup.py
├── footest
│   ├── test.py
```

`test.py` only has 1 line: `import foo`

In order for `test.py` to be able to import the package `foo` I install it with the command `pip3 install -e foo`.

Now a new folder called `foo.egg-info` is created under `foo/`

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar.py
│   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.egg-info
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO.txt
│   │   ├── requires.txt
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── top_level.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   └── setup.py
├── footest
│   ├── test.py
```

What's the purpose of this folder? I tried deleting it and `test.py` still ran properly. Is is just leftover garbage, similar to the `.o` files when compiling C projects? If so, is there a way to automatically remove it?

Comment: Not sure if any of these exactly answer your question on their own, but a quick read of each of them will probably clear this up for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384402/what-is-the-point-of-python-egg-files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256417/python-packages-and-egg-info-directories

Answer (score 1):

The package.egg-info saves meta data about your installed package like version.
It is used when you for example uninstall it, or "pip list" to see what is installed.

you can open it and take a look.

Comment: I read that the egg format is deprecated. Does this also cover the egg-info?